# Angular2 and Immutability :: Having multiple references

Tags: typescript, angular, immutability

So I just happened to read about Angular2's `ChangeDetector` that it checks objects for equality to determine if the DOM should be updated or not.

Now suppose I have an immutable `Person` object such that if your change the `name` property, the reference will change.

```
class Person {
  private _name: string;
  constructor(name: string) { this._name = name; }
  get name(): string { return this._name; }
  setName(name: string): Person {
    if (name === this.name) return this;
    return new Person(name);
  }
}
```

This sounds cool. But it gives me nightmares when I try to use it in a situation like so:

```
class System {
  students: {me: Person, parent: Person}[];
  parents: Person[];
}
```

Earlier on, I'd be able to do something like `this.parents[0].name = 'NewName'`.

But now I need to write the following code:

```
changeParentName(index: number, name: string) {
  let parent = this.parents[index];
  let newParent = parent.setName(name);
  if (parent === newParent) return;
  this.parents.splice(index, 1, newParent);

  this._parents = _.clone(this.parents);

  this._students = _.map(this.students, student => {
    if (student.parent !== parent) return student;
    return {
      me: student.me,
      parent: newParent
    }
  });
}
```

In order to ensure the following constraints are fulfilled:

1. If the name of the parent object changes, the reference should change.
2. If the other parent objects havent changed, their reference should stay the same.
3. If any parent changes, the `this.parents` reference should change as well.
4. If any parent changes, the corresponding student object should also change.
5. If the other student objects havent changed, their reference should stay the same.
6. If any student changes, the `this.students` reference should change as well.

Is using immutables really this complicated? Or am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: "am I missing something really obvious?": Unfortunately, no not really..There are libraries that can make some things easier (immutable.js, normalizr), but none are anything close to a silver bullet, and all have rather notable caveats.

Comment: I think this problem is too vague for stackoverflow. Maybe code review stack exchange is a better place.

Comment: @HerringtonDarkholme.. thanks for mentioning that.. i didnt know about that one.. ill give it a go as well.. :)